# Eloquent select items with several where clause on same relationship column

Tags: eloquent

I have a User model with a hasMany relations to model Cart.

Cart model has (among others) user_id and campaign_id.

I want to make a request which will grab all the users who have a cart with a specific campaign_id and also at least one of a list of campaign ids.
I came up with this request

```
$alistUsers = User::whereHas('cart', function($query) use($campaignId, $campaignIds){
                            $query->whereIn('campaign_id', $campaignIds)
                                    ->where('campaign_id', '=', $campaignId)
                            ;
                        })
                        ->get()
                        ;
```

which obviously returns 0 results since a cart item can't have several campaign_id.

I probably need to do something with sub selects but I can't find the correct answer.

If someone has an idea I'm all ears.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended up with 2 different queries

```
    $userIds = User::whereHas('cart', function($query) use($campaignId, $campaignIds){
                                $query->where('campaign_id', '=', $campaignId);
                            })
                            ->pluck('uuid')
                            ->toArray()
                            ;

   $iKnowUsers = User::whereHas('cart', function($query) use($userIds, $campaignIds){
                                $query->whereIn('campaign_id', $campaignIds)
                                        ->whereIn('user_id', $userIds );
                            })
                            ->get()
                            ->count();
```

But I'm not really happy with that so if someone has a cleaner answer I'll be interested to see it :)